# Purpose of this site as a beginner

Tags: discussion

I've asked a couple questions on the site and I've been reading through questions and answers, both on the regular site and on the meta. I'm not quite certain as to what the purpose of this site is.

Is it for experts to discuss nuances, beginners to get help, or somewhere in the middle? My questions are at a beginner level and they will be for a while as I learn. So another question I have is, should I go somewhere else?

Even having taken German classes and researching on my own, I assumed it would be okay to ask things here, where experts can quickly and easily give me direct and correct answers to questions. That is how I've experienced other sites in the stack exchange family (which is actually how I found this site).

I'm here to learn and improve as I can, so please let me know what I can do!

Comment: Actually the thing you can do is just **ask** and continue **asking** whatever your questions are :)

Comment: If there was an agreed upon and documented purpose of the site, then that would help to establish a consistent voting and moderating behaviour. I could not find such documentation.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: it is here in Meta where we as a community define the purpose of this site. There are a lot of such Meta posts already. Eventually all Meta discussions will merge into a still to be defined FAQ on site graduation. At present this FAQ is quite vague and open on purpose.

Comment: An FAQ which would also be presented to someone who wants to ask a question for the first time would be very beneficial. One could also point the new user to useful resources such as Duden.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz yeah sure, that is how it is done. It is the community (not a mod or a supervisor) who are asked to define this site by Meta discussions and  proposals. StackExchange gives us general rules and helps on how the site should go but all the fine tuning is up to us. This will need a vivid contribution of many community members here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is for **both**, experts and beginners (and everything in between), who wish to discuss the german language.

If you want to go somewhere else, we can't stop you, but you are welcome to stay ;)

Apart from asking questions and asking more questions you can also **answer** questions. The research you put into these is quite helpful in understanding the language.

Also it could be a good idea to participate [here on Meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com), where you can throw in your opinion on **what kind of site** this should be.
Also I recommend visiting our [German Language chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language), where you can practice your German or just chat with others here on the site ;)

Comment: Great answer, nothing to add.